# Android Weather app converting a String array to double having difficult

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help me please i tried to convert using double parse but not working for me. this is the array i want to loop to get temp

```
{"temp":17.49,"pressure":1022,"humidity":59,"temp_min":16,"temp_max":19}
```

I tried to type this way but it says some errors

```
 String  degree =jsonObject.getString("main");
            Log.i("systemmmm",degree);
    JSONArray arrr=new JSONArray(degree);

   for(int i=0;i<arrr.length();i++){
            JSONObject parts=arrr.getJSONObject(i);

          String temp;
            temp= parts.getString("temp");
            Log.i("heeeey",temp);

            //Log.i("gaaab", String.valueOf(qaybs.getDouble("temp")));
        }
```

the Error

> **W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"temp":17.49,"pressure":1022,"humidity":59,"temp_min":16,"temp_max":19}
>   of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an array, it's a JSON object. Arrays will have square brackets around them [  ]

Try

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(degree);
double temp = obj.getDouble("temp");
```